# Extend proto of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

In my project I am using Velocity and Processing.js. For my processing Sketch I need to extend the JSON Object. But when I do this, my Velocity animation stuff doesnt work anymore and I can't fix it.

Thats How I do the Extension:

```
Processing.prototype.JSONObject = JSON;

// extend JSON with primive getters
JSON.__proto__.getInt = function(keyname) {
    return parseInt(this[keyname]);
};
```

My idea was also to clone JSON into a new object and extend only this, but  I couldnt really get a real clone of it.

So what could be the right solution besides to rework my processing sketch?

Comment: The built-in [*JSON object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-json-object) is a plain object that inherits from *Object.prototype*. Modifying its `[[Prototype]]` is not a good idea (since that means modifying *Object.prototype*, so all native objects inherit those properties).

Comment: Yes. That sounds like my problem.

Comment: Why not simply assign to `JSON.getInt` directly?!

Comment: I tried of course, but console say getInt is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

what if you directly add a "getInt" to JSON object, something like this

```
JSON.getInt = function (obj , key) {
    return parseInt(obj[key]);
}
```

I see this working

```
var myObj = {"myKey" : 1};

JSON.getInt(myObj  , "myKey") // returns 1

OR window.JSON.getInt(myObj  , "myKey"); // same thing
```